# How do I copy my contact from an old Symbian phone to a new Windows Phone?

Tags: settings

I just switched from a Nokia C7 to a a Lumia 520. I have a back up my contacts, photos, and everything else. Now that I have my new Lumia 520, I don't know how to copy my contacts, pictures and video to my new device. Can someone point me to the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Transfer my Data` application by Nokia, that is already on your phone in the  apps list. If not, [download it here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/transfer-my-data/dc08943b-7b3d-4ee5-aa3c-30f1a826af02).

Answer (score -2):

Use [Nokia Suite](http://www.nokia.com/nokiasuite).

1. Install Nokia Suite.
2. Connect Nokia Suite with Nokia C7.
3. Use Nokia Suite to upload contacts, calendar etc to Microsoft OneDrive. *You need to use your Microsoft account for that.*
4. Sign-in with same Microsoft account to your Nokia Lumia 520.
5. Downloads your contacts and calendar from Microsoft OneDrive.
6. Photos, music, videos etc you can copy from your PC via USB cable to your Nokia Lumia 520.